# Is there any way to know if tmux is slow for a multi-robot experiment and if there are alternatives?

Tags: slam, multi-robot, optimization

I'm trying to run a multi-robot SLAM experiment, which is similar to that of [Kimera-Multi](https://github.com/MIT-SPARK/Kimera-Multi#examples--usage), that uses tmux to run numerous shell and ROS commands. I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and ROS noetic.

I'm running on an 8-robot experiment on [the campus hybrid dataset](https://github.com/MIT-SPARK/Kimera-Multi-Data), which has 8 robots and the bag files total to 363GB in size. The file runs over 20 commands, with 8 [front-ends](https://github.com/manthan99/VINS-COVINS-adaptation) and one back-end in a [centralized multi-robot system](https://github.com/VIS4ROB-lab/covins). I noticed the performance on some front-ends were fine, but some were extremely slow. For example, I took the following screenshot about an hour after the bag files finished playing[image] After 3 hours, I took another screenshot, and a couple frontends were still trying to optimize their PGO, while the backend was doing the same(finding new place recognition and PGO):[image]

I just wanted to know if using tmux slows down the process for ROS or if it's generally the load on the frontends/backend? I also wanted to know if simply using shell scripts could speed up the process? I'm only using tmux as there's a lot of repetitive commands to run and it's probably better to run them at the same time (especially the bag files). I also wanted to know for people who run multi-robot experiments(mainly simulations on a single computer) what's the ideal way to run such experiments?

Thanks,

Edit: From rubimat's suggestion, I split each window I used into a session. I don't know much about tmux, so I just used 3 different yaml files which are as below(some of these are my own scripts so they might not give much information in this context):

yaml1:

```
session_name: covins-setup

environment:
  ROBOT0: "acl_jackal"
  ROBOT1: "acl_jackal2"
  ROBOT2: "sparkal1"
  ROBOT3: "sparkal2"
  ROBOT4: "hathor"
  ROBOT5: "thoth"
  ROBOT6: "apis"
  ROBOT7: "sobek"
  ROSBAG0: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_acl_jackal.bag"
  ROSBAG1: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_acl_jackal2.bag"
  ROSBAG2: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sparkal1.bag"
  ROSBAG3: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sparkal2.bag"
  ROSBAG4: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_hathor.bag"
  ROSBAG5: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_thoth.bag"
  ROSBAG6: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_apis.bag"
  ROSBAG7: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sobek.bag"

options:
  default-command: /bin/bash
  
windows:
- window_name: setup
  layout: tiled  
  shell_command_before:
    - source ~/ws/covins_ws/devel/setup.bash

  panes:
    - roscore
    - sleep 2; rosrun covins_backend covins_backend_node
    - sleep 3; roslaunch ~/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/covins_backend/launch/tf.launch
    - sleep 3; rviz -d ~/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/covins_backend/config/covins.rviz
    - sleep 3; rosnode kill -a \
```

yaml2:

```
session_name: covins-frontends

environment:
  ROBOT0: "acl_jackal"
  ROBOT1: "acl_jackal2"
  ROBOT2: "sparkal1"
  ROBOT3: "sparkal2"
  ROBOT4: "hathor"
  ROBOT5: "thoth"
  ROBOT6: "apis"
  ROBOT7: "sobek"
  ROSBAG0: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_acl_jackal.bag"
  ROSBAG1: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_acl_jackal2.bag"
  ROSBAG2: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sparkal1.bag"
  ROSBAG3: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sparkal2.bag"
  ROSBAG4: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_hathor.bag"
  ROSBAG5: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_thoth.bag"
  ROSBAG6: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_apis.bag"
  ROSBAG7: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sobek.bag"

options:
  default-command: /bin/bash
  
windows:
- window_name: frontend
  layout: tiled
  shell_command_before:
    - source ~/ws/covins_ws/devel/setup.bash
    - sleep 5;
    - cd ~/catkin_vins/src/VINS-COVINS-adaptation/docker

  panes:
    - sleep 1; roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 launch_ros_kimera.launch ag_n:=0 input_ns:=$ROBOT0 --wait
    - sleep 2; source ~/svo_ws/devel/setup.bash; roslaunch svo_ros kimera_vio_stereo.launch ag_n:=1 input_ns:=$ROBOT1 --wait
    - sleep 3; roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 launch_ros_kimera.launch ag_n:=2 input_ns:=$ROBOT2 --wait
    - sleep 1; ./run_vins_covins_kimera.sh 3
    - sleep 2; ./run_vins_covins_kimera.sh 4
    - sleep 7; source ~/svo_ws/devel/setup.bash; roslaunch svo_ros kimera_vio_stereo.launch ag_n:=5 input_ns:=$ROBOT5 --wait
    - sleep 3; ./run_vins_covins_kimera.sh 6
    - sleep 8; roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 launch_ros_kimera.launch ag_n:=7 input_ns:=$ROBOT7 --wait

- window_name: svo_nodes
  layout: tiled
  shell_command_before:
    - source ~/ws/covins_ws/devel/setup.bash
    - sleep 12
  panes:
    - sleep 1; roslaunch covins_frontend svo_kimera_agent.launch ag_n:=1 input_ns:=$ROBOT1 --wait
    - sleep 2; roslaunch covins_frontend svo_kimera_agent.launch ag_n:=5 input_ns:=$ROBOT5 --wait
    - source ~/catkin_make_ws/devel/setup.bash; rosrun my_workspace write_trajectory.py --agent 1 --type svo
    - source ~/catkin_make_ws/devel/setup.bash; rosrun my_workspace write_trajectory.py --agent 5 --type svo
```

yaml3:

```
session_name: ros-bags

environment:
  ROBOT0: "acl_jackal"
  ROBOT1: "acl_jackal2"
  ROBOT2: "sparkal1"
  ROBOT3: "sparkal2"
  ROBOT4: "hathor"
  ROBOT5: "thoth"
  ROBOT6: "apis"
  ROBOT7: "sobek"
  ROSBAG0: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_acl_jackal.bag"
  ROSBAG1: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_acl_jackal2.bag"
  ROSBAG2: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sparkal1.bag"
  ROSBAG3: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sparkal2.bag"
  ROSBAG4: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_hathor.bag"
  ROSBAG5: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_thoth.bag"
  ROSBAG6: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_apis.bag"
  ROSBAG7: "$DATA_PATH/12_08_sobek.bag"

options:
  default-command: /bin/bash

windows:
- window_name: rosbags
  layout: tiled
  shell_command_before:
    - source ~/ws/covins_ws/devel/setup.bash
    - sleep 15;

  panes:
    - roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 kimera_bag.launch ag_n:=0 input_ns:=$ROBOT0 start:=0 use_ns:=true --wait #35
    - roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 kimera_bag.launch svo_prefix:=/image_thread ag_n:=1 input_ns:=$ROBOT1 start:=0 --wait
    - roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 kimera_bag.launch ag_n:=2 input_ns:=$ROBOT2 start:=0 use_ns:=true --wait
    - roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 kimera_bag.launch ag_n:=3 input_ns:=$ROBOT3 start:=0 use_ns:=false --wait
    - roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 kimera_bag.launch ag_n:=4 input_ns:=$ROBOT4 start:=0 use_ns:=false --wait
    - roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 kimera_bag.launch svo_prefix:=/image_thread ag_n:=5 input_ns:=$ROBOT5 start:=0 --wait
    - roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 kimera_bag.launch ag_n:=6 input_ns:=$ROBOT6 start:=0 use_ns:=false --wait
    - roslaunch ORB_SLAM3 kimera_bag.launch ag_n:=7 input_ns:=$ROBOT7 start:=0 use_ns:=true --wait
```

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google search tmux seems to have some issues with multiple long running processes. Are you using multiple panes/windows or multiple sessions to run the tasks on tmux? It may be worth to try running the processes all in different sessions instead of panes/windows.

A more 'ROS' way would be to write a launch file containing all executing commands for the bag files. This would save you time and might help the process to speed up.

Play bag from launch file: [ROS 1](https://answers.ros.org/question/62811/how-to-play-rosbag-using-launch-file/) / [ROS 2](https://answers.ros.org/question/341710/ros2-start-rosbag2-recording-from-launch-file/?answer=341955#post-id-341955)

Comment: I did try splitting each of my windows into individual sessions, but it doesn't seem to change much. As for the bag files, I do launch it individual launch files instead of directly invoking the command to play the rosbags. Due to the nature of the bag files having compressed images, I do have to run 2 image transport nodes for each bag file to uncompress the images, which may be a bottleneck. I'll probably also try limiting the number of topics as I only need image/IMU topics. I'll paste the yaml files I'm using in the main post to show what I'm doing.

Comment: You have a lot running at the same time, so I assume that tmux is not the bottleneck here. Limiting the topics to only those which are needed is definitely going to help. Also transporting raw images takes up a tremendous amount of bandwidth in you communication. Personally I would recommend to minimize the number of raw image topics as much as possible.

Comment: A possibility to for multi-robot simulations on limited hardware resources could be to run parts of the simulation (maybe one robot at a time) sequentially instead of in parallel. Also do you need the frontends during simulation? Since you are not doing real-time analysis anyway you could just look at it after it is done, right?

Comment: Hi rubimat, I did reduce all unnecessary topics from the bag files and split the runs into two parts: 4 robots first, then another 4 robots, so it is somewhat sequential (the backend I'm using is fine with sequential) and it did somewhat speed it up. My bag file originally publishes images as CompressedImage type so I was using the image transport package to change it to raw as the frontends only accepted sensor_msg/Image types. I guess a better way would be to change the source code to see if they can accept compressed images instead.

Comment: I recently worked on image pipelines and sending compressed images is way more efficient than sending raw images. I do not have quantitative data to prove that but it could definitely be noticed. Also if you can change the source code it might be worth to consider converting the nodes to [nodelets in ROS1](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) to make use of shared memory.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I haven't tried this approach yet so I'll look into it and see if it can improve my process.